# Excel side numbers

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

[image: Excel Screenshot]

On the above Excel screenshot, how can I get the side numbers (y-axis) to only go up to one or two? So it does not show `0.2`, `0.4` etc so it only says `0`, `1`, `2`, `3` etc.

Thanks,

Jack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to go through the axis settings. There, you have to change a couple of things. My Excel is German, so you will have to guess the names of things.

- **Left-click** the axis on the left side. It shows up selected with a box.
- **Right-click and select** `Format diagram` (or similar).

  [image: Context-menu]
- In the window, stay in the **top item of the list on the left** (`Axis options`).

  [image: Options window]
- On the right, the **top four properties** are what we want to change. They are all set to `Auto` by default. You can change them to reflect the look you want. I chose `0`, `3` and `1` for the first three and left the fourth value on `Auto` since it doesn't seem to do anything.

  [image: Change the first three values]

The diagram now looks like this:

[image: Altered diagram]